# External JS files are not loading in Angular CLI 7.1.4

Tags: jquery, angular, angular7

I'm new in Angular and installed the latest version of Angular. I also integrated Admin Theme which having bootstrap.css, other CSS and Other JS including jQuery. I googled 'How to use external .js file in Angular' but none of the solutions worked. I already installed jQuery, Bootstrap, and other jQuery plugins js through `npm install`

Below is my angular.json file.

```
"scripts": [
    "src/assets/js/main.js",
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",              
    "src/assets/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "node_modules/animsition/dist/js/animsition.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may load js at component or module level

Step 1: In component.ts file

```
public loadScript(url) {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = url;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

Step 2: In ngOnInit()

```
this.loadScript("assets/js/script.js");
```

This will load external js dynamically. This works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You are loading external js files before jQuery loading,You need to load jQuery first, so that jQuery code in you external js file will work, check below order

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",              
    "src/assets/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "node_modules/animsition/dist/js/animsition.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "src/assets/js/main.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your paths to the node_modules should be relative - `"../node_modules/`

Comment: for Angular 7 it should begin with "node_modules" without "../"

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to verify installed external JS files is to dump it's version numbers.

Edit your app.module.ts file and add this function:

```
declare var $: any;

function dumpVersions() {
    console.log(`Angular: ${VERSION.full}, jQuery: ${$.fn.jquery}, jQueryUI: ${$.ui.version}`);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
dumpVersions(); // <-- call

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
```

For VERSION you need to edit your import like this:

```
import { NgModule, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
```

Make sure you reference all scripts under node_modules like this:

```
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to load external js file from angular.json after navigate to another url, you need to create a service for loading the js files. after that import that service in the all component in which you want to load the functionality of that js and call the service on ngOnInit() method. below the github link are given how to create a service and component.ts file functionality. Thank You

[Click here](https://gist.github.com/Anj21/3fabe7b8ba4b617f962b656867bc1aab) for the solution,